# django-cms, template edit is not working

Tags: python, request, edit, django-cms

i am getting this error when i try to write something into `placeholder` directly in template. it cannot find the clue, i have done the steps exactly like shown in the docs

```
ValueError at /admin/cms/page/3/edit-plugin/4
The view home.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

here is my urls.py:

http://pastebin.com/zZX1MkMh

am i missing something else?

Thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E14bNX2A  here is the views.py

Answer (score 0):

If `request.path` does not match any pattern you provide, you will get the error `didn't return an HttpResponse object.`

add this to the end:

```
else:
    return HttpResponse(status=404)
```